# Corrplot correlation error: 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I am trying to create a Correlation plot for my dataset using 'corrplot' library. However I am getting an error as

> correlation error: 'x' must be numeric

Here is the sample of my dataset

```
 R.D.Spend Administration Marketing.Spend State   Profit
1  165349.2      136897.80        471784.1     1 192261.8
2  162597.7      151377.59        443898.5     2 191792.1
3  153441.5      101145.55        407934.5     3 191050.4
6  131876.9       99814.71        362861.4     1 156991.1
7  134615.5      147198.87        127716.8     2 156122.5
```

And my code is

```
library('corrplot')

M=cor(training_set)
corrplot(M,method = 'circle')
```

when I try to run my code the I get the error mentioned above. I dont understand what must be wrong as all the values in my dataset are Numeric.
My rest of the code is

```
dataset = read.csv('50_Startups.csv')

dataset$State=factor(dataset$State, 
                     levels = c('New York', 'California', 'Florida'),
                     labels = c('1','2','3'))

head(dataset,n=5)
# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
# install.packages('caTools')
library(caTools)
set.seed(123)
split = sample.split(dataset$Profit, SplitRatio = 0.8)
training_set = subset(dataset, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(dataset, split == FALSE)
```

Comment: It really is better to add your data example by posting the output of `dput(training_set)` or smaller `dput(head(training_set))` into your question, rather than this table. Because by reading in your table with `read.table()` your code gives us exactly what it's supposed to: a fancy colorful corrplot. Consider `str(training_set)` to evaluate if all data is numeric.

Comment: Ohh okay. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dataset$State` is a `factor`, `cor` expects only `numeric` variables.